# Error compilando com.google.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Actualizando las dependencias en android studio me encuentro con el siguiente error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

Anteriormente tenia las dependencias de la siguiente forma.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
     compileSdkVersion 24
     abuildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),           'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

El error me sale al cambiar la linea

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
```

a

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
```

Comment: Pelayo primeramente asegura no tener activada la opción "Offline Work"...

Comment: actualizaste el sdk de android studio?

Comment: Si, esta todo actualizado, al menos todo lo que se puede actualizar desde el sdk manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, había que actualizar también los plugins de firebase a la versión 9.2.0

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Revisa que no tengas activada la opción "Offline work" de Gradle, esa puede ser una razón por la cual no esta descargando la depenencia, veo que la versión si [existe](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project). Esta es la secuencia para acceder desde el menú :

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > Build tools > `Gradle`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sincroniza tu proyecto con los archivos Gradle!

Asegura actualizar la última versión de **Google Play Services** y **Google Repository** para que puedas soportar la última versión de `play-services-ads:9.2.0`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La opción offline work está desactivada...

Comment: @PelayoRodriguez Ok entonces actualiza Play Services, ve mi respuesta.

Comment: Está todo actualizado (Play Services Rev.31 y Google Repository Rev 29)

Comment: Sincroniza los archivos gradle con tu proyecto y dime si funciona.

Comment: Al sincronizar me da este error de gradle build: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

En el archivo Gradle de tu proyecto tienes

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Esa es la última versión del plugin al día de hoy. Hasta que no actualicen el plugin para que soporte la versión 9.2.0, vas a tener que regresar a la versión 9.0.2